# How does Bash path completion work with sudo?

Tags: bash, mount, sudo, path, autocomplete

Tab path completion does not work (at least on Ubuntu and AFAIK Arch) with

```
sudo mount <whatever>
```

The iso file I am trying to mount is not in `/etc/fstab`. If I just type

```
mount <whatever>
```

the completion works (but of course the command fails as I am not root). Apparently it is `sudo` that breaks it.

How can make completion work with sudo?

It is surprising that with

```
sudo umount <whatever>
```

completion works. How is it achieved? Does it look into `/etc/fstab`?

**Solution:** I just put a shell script into `/usr/local/bin` that calls `sudo mount ...` with the arguments passed to it. Completion works when calling this script since there is no `sudo` in the way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has not at all to do with `bash`, but it depends on the completions programmed in the package `bash-completion`.

From some comments in the file `/etc/bash_completion.d/mount`:

```
# mount(8) completion. This will pull a list of possible mounts out of
# /etc/{,v}fstab, unless the word being completed contains a ':', which
# would indicate the specification of an NFS server. In that case, we
# query the server for a list of all available exports and complete on
# that instead.
#

# umount(8) completion. This relies on the mount point being the third
# space-delimited field in the output of mount(8)
#
```

Also, you find in the main file `/etc/bash_completion` the following comment, that explicitly talk about `mount` and `umount` commands:

```
# A meta-command completion function for commands like sudo(8), which need to
# first complete on a command, then complete according to that command's own
# completion definition - currently not quite foolproof (e.g. mount and umount
# don't work properly), but still quite useful.
#
```

**Update**:
The comment about `mount` and `umount` commands was removed from `bash_completion` 
in the [commit](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/bash-completion/bash-completion.git/commit/?id=5051b1787ad384b342aba2f00a56130c25b6fc7f):

```
_command_offset: Restore compopts used by called command.

This fixes completions that rely on their compopts, most notably
mount(8).
Fixes bash-completion bug #313183.
```

[Released](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/bash-completion/bash-completion.git/tree/CHANGES?h=2.x#n360) in [`bash-completion 1.90`](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/bash-completion/bash-completion.git/tree/CHANGES?h=2.x#n314)

Answer (score 4):

This can easily be solved by looking into the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash#Auto-completion):

> It is useful to have the auto-complete feature (pressing the Tab key twice on the keyboard) after you type some command like `sudo`.
>
> To do this, add line(s) in this format to your `~/.bashrc` file:
>
> ```
> complete -cf your_command
> ```
>
> For example, to enable auto-complete after `sudo` and `man`:
>
> ```
> complete -cf sudo
> complete -cf man
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Please note that auto-complete works surprisingly well in case of `sudo umount`. As enzotib points out, this feature is broken with `mount` and last time I checked, it was broken on Arch too.

Comment: I just tried this on Arch and sudo mount /me<TAB> completes to the only path I have configured in `/etc/fstab` that starts with /media.

Comment: In my case, the file I am trying to mount is **not** in `/etc/fstab`. Could you please check this?

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't look in fstab. Bash completion looks for commands in path, aliases in bashrc and/or bash_profile and paths. So if you type something like `sudo mount /mnt/some_folder` it should auto-complete. Maybe when you did the `umount` you were in a relative path for your destination and it did an auto-complete.

Comment: Thanks. I am sure auto-complete does not work for `sudo mount /mnt/some_folder`, 100% sure. AFAIK it does not work on Arch Linux either. When I did the `umount` I was not in the relative path for the destination.

Answer (score -1):

I guess bash doesn't want to be too complex and stay portable, so they won't look in /dev to propose completion for a mount operation.

However when calling umount, it can easily look the output of df/mount/etc to know what devices are mounted and where.

Maybe zsh will provide completion for mount, heck zsh even autocomplete when doing an scp command...

Comment: The file I am trying to mount is an iso file in my home directory. The completion does not work. Oh, I have forgotten, completion with mount work if I do not use the sudo. It is the sudo that breaks it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Even using absolute paths? /home/user/myiso<TAB> -> myisofile.iso. debug with sudo echo $SHELL ; sudo pwd, hopefully it'll give you some insights.

Comment: Yes, with absolute paths. I will try the debugging you suggest. The debugging you suggest gives `/bin/bash` `/home/ali` as expected.