# bash does not autocomplete my command when using sudo?

Tags: bash, osx, sudo, autocomplete

I'm using SaltStack. I would like to auto-complete the minion name when calling the `salt` command.

The following line has been added into `~/.bashrc`:

```
complete -o default -o nospace -W "$(sudo ls -1 /var/cache/salt/master/minions)" salt
```

Then typing `salt inTab` → `salt integration-Tab`; I can see it works as expected:

```
$ salt integration-TabTab
integration-c   integration-u   integration-u2
```

To use with `sudo`, I have added `complete -cf sudo` into `~/.bashrc`, but it didn't work:

  ```
  sudo salt inTab
  ```

returned nothing.

I also have tried to install `bash_completion` and added the following lines to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

but no luck.

Did I miss something?

---

**Update**

Oh, the first thing I would like to say is sometimes it works:

```
$ sudo salt integration-TabTab
integration-c   integration-u   integration-u2
```

and sometimes it doesn't.

> So first, let's see how much your bash_completion package does.

How can I check that? Here's my function:

```sh
# a wrapper method for the next one, when the offset is unknown
_command()
{
    local offset i

    # find actual offset, as position of the first non-option
    offset=1
    for (( i=1; i <= COMP_CWORD; i++ )); do
        if [[ "${COMP_WORDS[i]}" != -* ]]; then
            offset=$i
            break
        fi
    done
    _command_offset $offset
}

# A meta-command completion function for commands like sudo(8), which need to
# first complete on a command, then complete according to that command's own
# completion definition - currently not quite foolproof (e.g. mount and umount
# don't work properly), but still quite useful.
#
_command_offset()
{
    local cur func cline cspec noglob cmd i char_offset word_offset \
        _COMMAND_FUNC _COMMAND_FUNC_ARGS

    word_offset=$1

    # rewrite current completion context before invoking
    # actual command completion

    # find new first word position, then
    # rewrite COMP_LINE and adjust COMP_POINT
    local first_word=${COMP_WORDS[$word_offset]}
    for (( i=0; i <= ${#COMP_LINE}; i++ )); do
        if [[ "${COMP_LINE:$i:${#first_word}}" == "$first_word" ]]; then
            char_offset=$i
            break
        fi
    done
    COMP_LINE=${COMP_LINE:$char_offset}
    COMP_POINT=$(( COMP_POINT - $char_offset ))

    # shift COMP_WORDS elements and adjust COMP_CWORD
    for (( i=0; i <= COMP_CWORD - $word_offset; i++ )); do
        COMP_WORDS[i]=${COMP_WORDS[i+$word_offset]}
    done
    for (( i; i <= COMP_CWORD; i++ )); do
        unset COMP_WORDS[i];
    done
    COMP_CWORD=$(( $COMP_CWORD - $word_offset ))

    COMPREPLY=()
    _get_comp_words_by_ref cur

    if [[ $COMP_CWORD -eq 0 ]]; then
        _compopt_o_filenames
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -c -- "$cur" ) )
    else
        cmd=${COMP_WORDS[0]}
        if complete -p ${cmd##*/} &>/dev/null; then
            cspec=$( complete -p ${cmd##*/} )
            if [ "${cspec#* -F }" != "$cspec" ]; then
                # complete -F <function>

                # get function name
                func=${cspec#*-F }
                func=${func%% *}

                if [[ ${#COMP_WORDS[@]} -ge 2 ]]; then
                    $func $cmd "${COMP_WORDS[${#COMP_WORDS[@]}-1]}" "${COMP_WORDS[${#COMP_WORDS[@]}-2]}"
                else
                    $func $cmd "${COMP_WORDS[${#COMP_WORDS[@]}-1]}"
                fi

                # remove any \: generated by a command that doesn't
                # default to filenames or dirnames (e.g. sudo chown)
                # FIXME: I'm pretty sure this does not work!
                if [ "${cspec#*-o }" != "$cspec" ]; then
                    cspec=${cspec#*-o }
                    cspec=${cspec%% *}
                    if [[ "$cspec" != @(dir|file)names ]]; then
                        COMPREPLY=("${COMPREPLY[@]//\\\\:/:}")
                    else
                        _compopt_o_filenames
                    fi
                fi
            elif [ -n "$cspec" ]; then
                cspec=${cspec#complete};
                cspec=${cspec%%${cmd##*/}};
                COMPREPLY=( $( eval compgen "$cspec" -- "$cur" ) );
            fi
        elif [ ${#COMPREPLY[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
            _filedir
        fi
    fi
}
```

---

> if you type `sudo mkdir`<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>,
>   does it show a list of directories?

Yes:

```
$ sudo mkdir TabTab
.FontForge/        .djangopypi2/      .ievms/            .ssh/              .wireshark-etc/
```

Comment: Chaining together command completions usually involves completion functions that invoke a function defined in the completion package called `_command_offset`. So first, let's see how much your bash_completion package does. If you remove the `complete -cf sudo` line from .bashrc, then logout and login again, and just use the support built in to bash_completion, do you see any special handling at all for sudo, e.g., if you type `sudo mkdir <tab><tab>`, does it show a list of directories?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: _if you type sudo `mkdir <tab><tab>`, does it show a list of directories?_ --> Yes, see my update in the original question.

Comment: If completion chaining is sometimes working and sometimes not, the first thing I'd check is the completion definition for `sudo` when completions are not working. Do this by typing  `complete|grep sudo`. Bash on OSX reads its init files in nonintuitive ways (see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/13019), so my hunch is that sometimes not all your completion definitions are being read in or they are being superseded by unwanted definitions.

Comment: Possibly related: [How does Bash path completion work with sudo?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30827/80216)

Answer (score 3):

Check `set -o` to see if maybe `posix` mode is enabled. If so, disable with `set +o posix`

In "posix" mode, bash's tab-completion is for some reason disabled in "vi-mode". I've not seen any explanation why this behavior is so, nor why it's specific to vi-mode, so I didn't bother explaining.

PS: This answer is more suited for someone who stumbles upon the question via a search engine... not for your particular setup.

**Update**:
Chet Ramey [says](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gnu.bash.bug/NAGM6Yc0bl8/Daz4y3mILrsJ):

> in POSIX mode, the vi editing mode should not map tab to complete.
>   This is because POSIX.2 completely specifies the behavior of the vi
>   editing mode, and the standard requires tab to be mapped to self
>   insert by default.

Comment: Question about [bash completion on posix mode](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132135/bash-completion-on-posix-mode)

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer:

- Install [`bash-completion`](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion)
- Source [`bash_completion`](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/bash_completion) on `Bash` startup
- Add your compspec on `Bash` startup
- Don't overwrite `sudo` compspec with `complete -cf sudo`

I suppose that you use `MacOSX` with `brew`.

Try:

```
brew update
brew install bash-completion
brew info bash-completion
# bash-completion: stable 1.3
. $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
complete -p sudo
```

You should see something like this:

```
complete -F _root_command sudo
```

Test:

```
function _comp_foo() { COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W 'a b c' -- "$2")); }
complete -F _comp_foo foo
```

Type `foo` <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>
You should see `a b c`

Type `sudo foo` <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>
You should see `a b c`

Then remove `complete -fc sudo` from your initialisation files (`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` etc)
Add the following lines to your initialisation files:

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  . $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi

# Your compspec here
complete -o default -o nospace -W "$(sudo ls -1 /var/cache/salt/master/minions)" salt
```

Reopen terminal.
Type `complete -p sudo`.
You should see `complete -F _root_command sudo`.

Type `complete -p salt`.
You should see something like this:

```
complete -o default -o nospace -W 'a
b
c' salt
```

**bash-completion2.* note**:
You can install `bash-completion2`: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/19258
But:

- `2.*` works with `Bash 4.*`
- `2.*` uses the `-D` option for compspecs lazy loading. So, `complete -p sudo` outputs `complete: sudo: no completion specification` until you type `sudo`<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

`sudo` doesn't give you an login shell unless you ask for it with `-i`.  So you'll find that without it you'll need to load the system's completions:

```
. /etc/bash_completion
```

If you run with `-i`, then `$HOME` will be `~root`, and so anything written to the user's `~/.bashrc` won't get read.  If you can separate out the completion stuff from the rest of your `~/.bashrc`, source that with `.` and that should work.

Comment: But this question is about somebody typing a `sudo` command *into his default shell*.  `sudo` hasn't started running yet, so ***its*** behavior is irrelevant; this is all about the behavior of the user's shell.